# jQuery plugIn to manage forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, plugin

I have just created my first jQuery plugin. I am looking to suggestions on how to improve it, leading to a code optimization.

```
(function($) {
   var plugin_name = 'W.jQuery.FieldEvents';
   var name_space = 'wFieldEvents';  
   var methods = {
      init : function(options) { 
         return this.each(function(){
            var field = $(this);
            var settings = {
               'edit_button' : '',
               'submit_button':'',
               'error_message':'value not found',
               callback:function(){
                  alert('no call back defined for'+field.attr('id'))
               }
            };
            settings = $.extend(settings, options);
            var data = field.data(name_space);
            var edit_button = $(settings.edit_button);
            var submit_button = $(settings.submit_button);
            if (!data) {
               $(this).data(name_space, {
                  submit_button : submit_button,
                  edit_button :edit_button,
                  callback:settings.callback,
                  error_message:settings.error_message
               });
            }
            methods.enable_submit.call(field); 
         });
      },
      disable_edit: function(){
         return this.each(function(){
            var field = $(this);
            var data = field.data(name_space);
            //alert(data.edit_button.attr('id'));
            data.edit_button.attr('disabled','disabled').off('click.'+name_space).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
         });
      },
      enable_submit : function()
      {
         return this.each(function(){
            var field = $(this);
            var data = field.data(name_space);
            //alert('working');
            //alert('enabled submit called for '+field.attr('id'));
            methods.disable_edit.call(field);
            field.removeAttr('disabled');
            data.submit_button.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
            data.submit_button.on('click.'+name_space,function(){
               methods.submit.call(field);
            });
            field.focus();
         });
      },
      enable_edit: function()
      {
         return this.each(function(){
            var field = $(this);
            var data = field.data(name_space);
            field.attr('disabled','disabled');
            data.edit_button.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
            data.edit_button.on('click.'+name_space,function(){
               methods.enable_submit.call(field);
            });
         });
      },
      disable_submit: function(){
         return this.each(function(){
            var field = $(this);
            var data = field.data(name_space);
            field.attr('disabled','disabled');
            data.submit_button.attr('disabled','disabled').off('click.'+name_space).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
            methods.enable_edit.call(field);
         });
      },
      show_error: function(){
         return this.each(function(){
            var field = $(this);
            var data = field.data(name_space);
            //alert(data.error_message);
            field.focus();
            $(dialog_id).html(data.error_message);
            $(dialog_id).dialog('open');
         });
      },
      submit:function(){
         return this.each(function(){
            //alert('submit called');
            var field = $(this);
            var data = field.data(name_space);
            var value = field.val();
            if(value != '')
            {
               methods.disable_submit.call(field);
               data.callback();
            }
            else
            {
               methods.show_error.call(field);
            }
         });
      },
      destroy : function() {
         return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data(name_space);
            // Namespacing FTW
            $(window).W.jQuery.FieldEvents(name_space);
            data.wFieldEvents.remove();
            $this.removeData(name_space);
         });
      }
   };

   $.fn.W_FieldEvents  = function( method ) {

      // Method calling logic
      if ( methods[method] ) {
         return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
      } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
         return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
      } else {
         $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on '+plugin_name );
         return false;
      }    

   };
})(jQuery);
```

**Usage example:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#po_number').W_FieldEvents({
     'submit_button' : '#po_number_submit',
     'edit_button'   : '#po_number_edit',
     'error_message' : 'PO# number not found',
     callback        : function(){
       alert('submit done');
     }
   });

});
```

Comment: It's always useful to run the code through [jslint](http://jslint.org) or [jshint](http://www.jshint.com). For instance, both caught that `dialog_id` is not defined anywhere but used in `show_error()`. You also have an implicit global (`data` in `destroy()`) which neither jshint or jslint caught (I just spotted it by chance).

Comment: What about data management, am i doing it correctly? is this good approach to save data for each element in its jQuery data attribute. Is there a way to store elements data in a single datastore? I have also noticed that if i call this plugin twice on an element it will double map the events. i.e showing two error messages instead of one. i want to avoid it, is there any way out?

Comment: You could store everything in a closure, I suppose, but I see no reason to not use `.data()`. Seems pretty straightforward to me (disclaimer: I've never had to make a jQuery plugin, so perhaps someone with more experience has a different opinion). As for the double events, I'd suggest you check for existing data on the elements. If it's there, it's been set up before, _and_ you can merge the existing settings and the passed-in options, instead of merging with the default options. Then calling it twice on the same element won't double the event, but will update the settings.

Comment: Waqasalieee, you don't need `name_space` as well as `plugin_name`. Simply use the `plugin_name` as the namespace name, and start the supervisor with `$.fn[plugin_name] = function(method) {`. @Flambino, with this pattern, you can only store whole-plugin stuff in the closure; no closure within the pattern is scoped to be element-specific so data must be stored in the DOM with `.data()`.

Comment: Beetroot, if am using this plugin name ' W.jQuery.FieldEvents ' then it contains dots (.), i thought it will create problems in event binding code i.e : edit_button.on('click.'+name_space,function(){//code});

Answer (score 3):

You can refactor the init function.

```
init : function(options) {
         var defaults = {
           'edit_button' : '',
           'submit_button':'',
           'error_message':'value not found'
          };
          options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
         return this.each(function(){
            var field = $(this);
            if (!options.hasOwnProperty('callback') ) {
              options.callback = function(){
                alert('no call back defined for'+field.attr('id'))
              }
            }             
            var data = field.data(name_space);
            var edit_button = $(options.edit_button);
            var submit_button = $(options.submit_button);
            if (!data) {
               $(this).data(name_space, {
                  submit_button : submit_button,
                  edit_button :edit_button,
                  callback:options.callback,
                  error_message:options.error_message
               });
            }
            methods.enable_submit.call(field);
         });
      },
```

As Flambino mentioned run your code through [JSlint](http://www.jslint.com)